# Connected to wireless network, but no Internet

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router

Here's my problem.  I have a Netgear WGR614v6 wireless router and was able to set up the wireless network (I can send documents to my printer wirelessly), but I cannot connect to the Internet through the router.  I have no problems when I connect the computer directly to the modem.  When I attempt to connect through the router both wirelessly and by the Ethernet cable I have no Internet access.  My wireless connection status says there is no IPv4 nor IPv6 internet access.  Both are set to obtain an IP and DNS Server address automatically.  Signal quality on the wireless router is excellent. I have tried power-cycling the router and modem with no luck.

This is what I have when I did ipconfig /all:

```
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : xxxxxxx
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8187SE Wireless LAN PCIE Netwo
rk Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 70-F1-A1-D1-DC-3F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5153:b143:acf7:3e8d%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, November 12, 2010 5:16:05 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, November 13, 2010 5:16:05 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 242282913
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-BC-31-9A-88-AE-1D-4E-23-15

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-AE-1D-4E-23-15
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{4BEE441B-C244-4642-AE71-745D1199E5DE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9A2C832A-3E88-42DB-8D70-FFA7F014AFC6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

The first day I set up the router I was able to get Internet wireless and by Ethernet through the router.  But since then (2 weeks) I've been having this problem. I am using Windows 7.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you click Troubleshoot Problems within Network and Sharing Center?

Comment: Can you connect into your router and look at your WAN settings? Is it picking up the proper information? Can you ping from your router to your Primary DNS? Can you ping Google.com? Can you ping 74.125.19.104?

Answer (score 5):

Try completely resetting the router, i.e. hold any reset button down for 30 seconds, or log into the management interface and use any "Reset to Default"-like options.

As far as taking an actual look at your issue, it might be a DNS issue.  Check to be sure your getting the right DNS servers via DHCP and that they are reachable.  Alternatively, you can try disabling ipv6 if you don't need it.

Comment: +1 - very likely DNS.  Your router is 192.168.1.1, and is also your DNS server - can you ping it?  As others suggest, can you ping remote IPs?  Standard troubleshooting steps that need to be taken for people to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the firmware on the router

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is, as @ultrasawblade noted, a DNS issue - try going to http://74.125.95.105 and if you get Google, you need to add your DNS servers to your router. DNS is the system that allows you to resolve domain names to IP addresses. There are lots of free public DNS servers - most ISPs have their own, but some popular ones can be found here: http://theos.in/windows-xp/free-fast-public-dns-server-list/

Answer (score 0):

First off, I've had terrible luck with NetGear Routers, and would **highly** recommend not using them.  With that said however, try following these steps:

1. Unplug the power cords completely from both the router and the cable modem (Leave the cable and CAT5 cables connected.
2. Plug back in the cable modem and wait for ALL connections to be initiated (at least 2 mins)
3. Plug back in the Router and wait for ALL connection to be initiated
4. Try your internet connection

This was the process that I had to go through on a regular basis with my old netgear router.

If this doesn't work, then I suggest borrowing or purchasing a new router to test and see if the issue really is the router.  Other things to try is changing and double checking the CAT5 cables connecting the router and the modem.  They do get used and over time can be broken. (Although I doubt this is the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I FINALLY got it to work.  What I did was I went into the Router Manager and completely reset it as ultrasawblade suggested.  I had tried this previously and it did not work.  However, this time around I did not go through the initial set up and left all the settings as is, with the exception of changing the security settings.  Not sure what was different, but it did the trick.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: You should mark Ultrasawblade's answer as correct them